# iOS 8 status bar background orientation in landscape mode

Tags: ios, ios8, uikit

In iOS8, in the viewDidLoad method of my viewController I set the main view programatically using the following code:

```
CGRect appRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
rootView = [[RootView alloc] initWithFrame: appRect];
[self setView: rootView];
```

The app only runs in landscape left mode (I control this from the plist file of the application).
This is what the view looks like after it set it:
[image]

Even though the app is in landscape mode, the white bar that should be under the status bar appears as if the app is in portrait mode.
Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Edit:
Running this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]));
```

outputs: `{{0, 0}, {1024, 20}}`

Edit: 
I added a background color for the root view:

```
rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

This is what the app looks like now:
[image]

Comment: @holex thanks, I tried that and it seems fine {{0, 0}, {1024, 20}}. I updated the question. So the status bar is ok, but the white area appears as if it would be in portrait mode

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of where you are setting "Portrait only".

Comment: Do you mean a screenshot of the plist configuration? It's actually set to be landscape only: http://tinypic.com/r/5cr6g/8

Comment: Ah right. In your question you said "The app only runs in portrait mode". You should be setting "landscape only" in the Build Settings under "Deployment Info" not in the plist. They are sort of the same but use the tick boxes when they are available. Can you show a screen shot of this bit in Xcode... http://i.stack.imgur.com/VHd1d.png

Comment: It sounds like you have conflicting settings between the plist that you edited and the orientation settings. Possibly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's set to landscape left in both the plist and the Xcode interface:

Comment: No worries. Just wanted to make sure :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my case was that in my appdelegate the my `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application` method:
I wasn't setting the root view controller. Instead I was doing this:

```
viewController = [[BoardViewController alloc] init];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[window addSubview: [viewController view]];
```

Once I changed that the root view frame covered the whole window and the status bar background was where it was supposed to be:

```
viewController = [[BoardViewController alloc] init];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

I got the idea from this answer: [iOS 8 - Launching the application in Landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211561/ios-8-launching-the-application-in-landscape-mode)